# add key and value to an existing array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I need to add key and value to an existing array and don't seem to be able to get it together.

My existing array when printed looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 787
            [name] => Steve
            [surname] => Ryan
            [email] => Steve@hotmail.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1057
            [name] => Peter
            [surname] => Smith
            [email] => Peter.Smith@yahoo.com
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1058
            [name] => Chris
            [surname] => Gill
            [email] => chrisgill@gmail.com
        )

)
```

I need to add a few details to this array on the fly from a `string` that looks like this:

```
Topher:Topher1234@mac.com
Elvis:elvispresley@gmail.com
Marilyn:marilyn.monroe@hotmail.com
```

Each entry is seperated by a `new line` and the name and email address is seperated by a `:`

So in the end my array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 787
            [name] => Steve
            [surname] => Ryan
            [email] => Steve@hotmail.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1057
            [name] => Peter
            [surname] => Smith
            [email] => Peter.Smith@yahoo.com
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1058
            [name] => Chris
            [surname] => James
            [email] => chrisjames@gmail.com
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => Topher
            [surname] => 
            [email] => Topher1234@mac.com
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => Elvis
            [surname] => 
            [email] => elvispresley@gmail.com
        )
    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => Marilyn
            [surname] => 
            [email] => marilyn.monroe@hotmail.com
        )

)
```

I looked at array_push but couldn't work it out.

Any help with this is very much sppreciated.

C

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Array push should word or just `$array['key'] = $value`

Comment: You might be looking for $myarray[] = $appendedValue;

Equivalent of javascript's myarray.push(appendedValue);

Comment: Thanks @HunterF I'll check that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP Arrays' [] operator is the same as pushing a value to the end of an array.

```
$arr[] = 'new element in array';
```

A full solution to your example would be

```
$CharacterInput = <<<EOT
Topher:Topher1234@mac.com
Elvis:elvispresley@gmail.com
Marilyn:marilyn.monroe@hotmail.com
EOT;

$lines = explode("\n", $CharacterInput);

$People = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($name, $email) = explode(':', $line);

    $entry = array(
        'id' => null,
        'name' => $name,
        'surname' => null,
        'email' => $email,
    );

    // cast the entered data array to an object,
    // which is explicitly stated in the example output.
    // For plain arrays, remove the following line.
    $entry = (object) $entry;

    $People[] = $entry;
}

print_r($People);
```

which outputs

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
 (
 [id] => 
 [name] => Topher
 [surname] => 
 [email] => Topher1234@mac.com
 )

 [1] => stdClass Object
 (
 [id] => 
 [name] => Elvis
 [surname] => 
 [email] => elvispresley@gmail.com
 )

 [2] => stdClass Object
 (
 [id] => 
 [name] => Marilyn
 [surname] => 
 [email] => marilyn.monroe@hotmail.com
 )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
$string = "Topher:Topher1234@mac.com\nElvis:elvispresley@gmail.com\nMarilyn:marilyn.monroe@hotmail.com";
$string = explode("\n", $string);
$result = array(); # or your existing array
foreach($string as $chunk){
        $to_array = new stdClass();
        $to_array->id = null;
        $to_array->surname = null;
        list($to_array->name, $to_array->email) = explode(':', $chunk);
        $result[] = $to_array;
}
print_r($result);
```

[Codepad sample](http://codepad.org/1DFfyNni)

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [surname] => 
            [email] => Topher1234@mac.com
            [name] => Topher
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [surname] => 
            [email] => elvispresley@gmail.com
            [name] => Elvis
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [surname] => 
            [email] => marilyn.monroe@hotmail.com
            [name] => Marilyn
        )

)
```

Answer (score -2):

Suppose $arr is your existing array variable, do it as given below.

```
$arr[] =  array(
            ['id'] => '',
            ['name'] => 'Topher',
            ['surname'] => '',
            ['email'] => 'Topher1234@mac.com'
);
```